# Mongo Db gte returning wrong values

Tags: mongodb

I have struggled to identify what I could be doing wrong but still cant identify.
This is my mongo db version
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TK3cC.png)

this is the wrong result when I query.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gLtLb.png)

And when I input anything greater than 38(value in the db) I get this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8FicA.png)

Comment: I see no problem here. In your first image you are asking for documents with `Amount` greater than (or equal to) 36 and get a response with a document with `amount` 38. On your second image you are looking for documents with  `Amount` greater than (or equal to) 39, but you don't have any...

Comment: @nimrodserok your are right. Thanks want not reasoning in that directions